# 1.9 compared with magento C.E 1.8

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Does anyone know where I could get the information of all that have changed in C.E 1.9 when compared with magento C.E 1.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check here about the features of 1.9 version and difference in this blog :

http://www.fmeextensions.com/blog/magento-ce-1-8-vs-1-9-new-features-difference-comparison/

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html